# SharePoint REST API - Get 2 items only

Tags: rest

I want to query Calendar list and get the upcoming 2 events. How should I form my query ?

This is the query I have to read the items from required list :

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Event')/items?$filter=Active eq 1"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `$limit` in conjunction with `orderby=ID desc` to restrict no of returned users

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Event')/items?$filter=Active eq 1$limit=2$orderby=ID desc
```

You can also use `$top=2`

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Event')/items?$filter=Active eq 1$top=2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Event')/items?$filter=Active eq 1$top=2"
```